# PySpark: how to calculate the average up to a certain date?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am using an EMR notebook with Pyspark >= 3.1

I have 4 columns:

1. ID_CLIENT: a unique index for the client
2. IDX_TRX: a unique index for the transaction. Actually this is an alphanumeric column and the index does not indicate any order. The numerical index in this example is for easy explanation.
3. dt: datetime, date of the transaction
4. AVERAGE_TRX: Amount of the transaction

I want to calculate the following column 'AVERAGE_TRX':

```
+---------+--------+----------+-----+------------+
|ID_CLIENT| IDX_TRX|        dt|AMOUNT|AVERAGE_TRX|
+---------+--------+----------+-----+------------+
|        A|      01|2018-06-14|   10|        NULL| # 1st trx there are no records
|        B|      01|2018-06-14|    5|        NULL| # 1st trx there are no records
|        A|      02|2018-06-15|   20|          10| # 10 / 1
|        A|      03|2018-06-15|   30|          15| # (10 + 20) / 2
|        B|      02|2018-06-16|   10|           5| # 5 / 1
|        A|      04|2018-06-16|   20|          20| # (10 + 20 + 30) / 3
|        A|      05|2018-06-17|    5|          20| # (10 + 20 + 30 + 20) / 4
|        B|      03|2018-06-17|   10|         7.5| # (5 + 10) / 2
|        A|      06|2018-06-18|   15|          17| # (10 + 20 + 30 + 20 + 5) / 5
|        B|      04|2018-06-18|   10|   8.3333334| # (5 + 10 + 10) / 3
+---------+--------+----------+-----+------------+
```

how can I calculate the last column?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -
This will mess up the order of records but it should have desired value for rows.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = (Window.partitionBy('ID_CLIENT')
      .orderBy('IDX_TRX')
      .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)) # -1 is to do cumulative calculation up until the previous row.

df = df.withColumn('AVERAGE_TRX', avg('AMOUNT').over(w))
```

```
df.show()
+---------+--------+----------+-----+------------+
|ID_CLIENT| IDX_TRX|        dt|AMOUNT|AVERAGE_TRX|
+---------+--------+----------+-----+------------+
|        A|      01|2018-06-14|   10|        null| 
|        A|      02|2018-06-15|   20|        10.0| 
|        A|      03|2018-06-15|   30|        15.0| 
|        A|      04|2018-06-16|   20|        20.0| 
|        A|      05|2018-06-17|    5|        20.0|  
|        A|      06|2018-06-18|   15|        17.0| 
|        B|      01|2018-06-14|    5|        null| 
|        B|      02|2018-06-16|   10|         5.0| 
|        B|      03|2018-06-17|   10|         7.5| 
|        B|      04|2018-06-18|   10|   8.3333334| 
+---------+--------+----------+-----+------------+
```

Comment: You can use avg("AMOUNT").over(w) instead of sum('AMOUNT').over(w) / count('AMOUNT').over(w)